# Question regarding add node with text within TkiZ package?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I followed an example from TikZ manual, and modify mine to add an extra node with text below a given node. This is the example from TiKZ manual,
[image]

And here is the code,
[image]

So I modified my code to fit the example above,

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\def\xcolorversion{2.00}
\def\xkeyvalversion{1.8}

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[version=0.96]{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,automata,backgrounds,petri,positioning}
\title{\textbf{Solution for Chapter 1}}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}
\maketitle

\begin{description}
    \item[1.1] The following are the state diagrams for two DFAs, $M_1$, and $M_2$. Answer the following question 
    about each of these machines.\\     
    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto]
    \node[state,initial]    (q_1)                           {$q_1$}; 
    \node[state,accepting]  (q_2)   [right=of q_1]          {$q_2$}; 
    \node[state]            (q_3)   [below right=of q_1]    {$q_3$}; 

    \path[->]
    (q_1) edge  [bend left]     node {a}            (q_2)
    (q_1) edge  [loop above]    node {b}            (q_1)
    (q_2) edge  [bend left]     node {a,b}          (q_3)
    (q_3) edge  [bend left]     node {a}            (q_2)
    (q_3) edge  [bend left]     node {b}            (q_1)

    \node [below=4cm, text width=4cm] at (q_3)
    {
        something
    }   
    ;
    \end{tikzpicture}\\     
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

But the `pdflatex` compiler run forever, it's just freezed completely. I don't know where did I miss? It seemed logically correct. Any idea or suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: I figured it out. An annoying `;` after `\path` cost me a lot of times :(.